# Create a report for Unsent Email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio

I know this is possible since I've used it in previous organizations. I'm looking to build a report or activity/automation where we can paste the JobID of a send and find out the difference between the people in the original list that was uploaded and the people that it was actually sent to and the reason - for Salesforce MC.
For example, if the original list had 100 contacts, but only 80 were sent WHO were the other 20 (email address or subscriber key), WHAT reason were they not uploaded (unsubscribed, undeliverable).
I've tried this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313980&type=1&mode=1 but it doesn't provide the detail I need to walk me through the process of setting this up.
Thank you

Comment: please add a tag for whether this is SFMC or Pardot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The not-sent reason can only be found in the [NotSent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5) Tracking Extract and the [NotSentEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/notsentevent.htm) SOAP API object.

For the first, you'll need to create a Not Sent data extension to accept the import.  Then you can configure a Tracking Extract in Automation Studio with these steps.

1. Extract (check the Not Sent Box)
2. Transfer (from Safehouse)
3. Transfer Unzip (to extract NotSent.csv/NotSent.txt)
4. Import (NotSent.csv/NotSent.txt)

It's involved, but this is a stable method for getting this data into a Data Extension.

For the API method, you can write a Script Activity using SSJS and WSProxy pull that data and write it to a Data Extension. This method is subject to the 30-minute timeout and is not advisable if you have high send volumes.